# Does obtaining a variable via lexical scope count as dependency injection?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, theory

Note: If I misuse termanology, please let me know.

Here are two scenarios:

A)

```
var fetch = /* some implementation */

function getSomething(httpClient) {
  return httpClient('https://go-get-something.com/api')
}

getSomething(fetch)
```

B)

```
var fetch = /* some implementation */

function getSomething() {
  return fetch('https://go-get-something.com/api')
}

getSomething()
```

I would consider A as "parameter injection" or maybe "constructor injection". The fetch function is being explicitly provided to a function which requires it as a dependency.

The `fetch` variable is available on the window. This is the lexical scope of the `getSomething` function.

If I don't explicitly pass the fetch variable (example B) to the function, instead getting it from the lexical scope, would that still count as some form of dependency injection?

If not, is there a formal name for providing dependencies to a function closure like this?

Comment: *shrug* It's DI, but by accident. ("Weak DI"?) And probably not a great idea because the control over what implementation ends up being used may come down to something as vague as load order.

Comment: It's a global variable?